# TemplateDoesNotExit post_list.html

Tags: python, django

I have stumbled upon a problem where it tries to look for a template I did not even indented it to. My html files name is home.html but it looks for post_list.html. Here are the few of the files:

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import HomeView

urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.home, name = "home")
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name = "home"),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post

# Create your views here.
#def home(request):
#   return render(request, 'home.html', {}) 

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_score = 'home.html' 
]
```

Here is the directory.
[image]

The commented lines are the ones that works, but when I try the class HomeView it gives me error.

```
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
myblog/post_list.html
```

Comment: Can you share your `HomeView`? If you want to look for `home.html`, then you need to specify that in the view. If it is a `ListView`, it will by default use `modelname_list.html`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry copied the urls.py twice, I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The roots that Django searches are the `app_name/templates`. Since the path is `myblog/post_list.html`, you need to put a `post_list.html` template under:

```
.
└── myblog
    └── templates
        └── myblog
            ├── index.html
            └── post_list.html
```

You can specify another name with:

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'myblog/home.html'
```

Comment: but i dont even need it to look for `post_list.html`.

Comment: @ShahinMamedov: it is `template_name`, not `template_score`. Normally you also add the app name, to avoid collisions with other apps.

Comment: What ever I do it still looks for `post_title.htlm`. You can check out HomeView class I posted above, I also did as you said, added a folder inside `templates` folder and moved `home.html` inside it.

Comment: @ShahinMamedov: but did you use `template_name` instead of `template_score`?

Comment: I totally skipped that part! but why would variable name interfere with it?

Comment: @ShahinMamedov: let me put it differently: Why would `template_score` have any impact? Django simply defines certain attributes and attaches semantics to it. If you use another variable name, it is just a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Your template file should be stored in a subfolder named accordingly to your app, like this

```
templates/myblog/post_list.html
```